# VPN or SSH or what option would work for what I want to do?

Tags: ssh, vpn, routing

I need to have my Internet connection for work to show up as being from a specific city.  They state I am not allowed to work from anywhere other than the address on my record for security reasons. Unfortunately for me, I cannot be at home for a few weeks due to a family emergency.  Work will not allow me to work from the other location and I have to use their systems.

Is there a way to make it look like I am working from a specific place such as Longmont, CO even through I am in Phoenix, AZ?  I do not have admin rights on the work system so I cannot just leave the computer in Longmont and access the system through Teamviewer or the like.  Further, my headset needs to be connected to the work system and therefore I need to have the system with me.

I have been told if I don't work for 2 weeks, I will lose my job and I cannot afford to do that.  Their system uses a VPN to connect to their servers.

Do you have any suggestions on how to get around this issue?

Comment: BTW, I don't recommend you to do such VPN re-tunneling. Just be honest and explain your situation. There is no such things as "easily replaceable" personnel with zero training.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is essentially asking how to bypass explicit security policies.